# Mysterious box floats on second display and won't go away

Tags: desktop, window-manager, ui

I don't know where this comes from. I can't click it, it is only present on the second display; when I mirror displays it goes away.
Does anyone have an idea what this could be?

[image]
I realise a reboot/logout will probably fix it, but I'm curious as to what this is and whether there is some method which will tell me, to which process it belongs.

System: 10.10.5, Mbp 9,2

**Edit**: Turns out it was Finder. When logging out, I got a popup saying that *some operations are still in progress*, although I don't know what.

Comment: Can You show us the screenshot? Also try to use Accessibility Inspector: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232416/how-to-identify-process-from-a-toolbar-icon

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Whoops, totally forgot.