# How to find the application that controls system dialog window

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, system-settings

I am trying to change the default browser between Chrome and Safari without needing user input except for initially running it.

I found this utility that takes care of the difficult bit:

- https://github.com/kerma/defaultbrowser

It can be installed using Homebrew by running:

```
brew defaultbrowser
```

However when you run it a dialogue box shows up asking if I want to change browser. I want to press the "Yes "button using AppleScript. Below is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot that comes up when you call <code>default browser</code>]

I want to find the application that contains this window. Is there a better way to find out where the window is rather than go through them all?

I've tried foremost window but it seems to return the foremost program. Here's some program I've tried:

```
tell application "System Events"
        tell process "SecurityAgent"
            click button 1 of window 1
        end tell
        delay 0.2
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a *window* that is a **system dialog**, or **alert**, type of *window*, and you do not know which *application* it belongs to, you can try using *code* such as the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* to determine the *name* of the *application* to which it belongs:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get name of every application process ¬
        whose role description of window 1 is "system dialog"
```

Or:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    get name of every application process ¬
        whose accessibility description of window 1 is "alert"
```

---

That said, the *application process* you want **System Events** to interact with is: **CoreServicesUIAgent**

For example, if **Google Chrome** is my *default browser* and I run, e.g.:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/defaultbrowser 'safari'"
```

Then this *dialog box* appears:

[image]

To click the **Use “Safari”** *button*, use:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click button "Use “Safari”" of ¬
        window 1 of application process "CoreServicesUIAgent"
```

Note: You can also use `click button 1` instead of `click button "Use “Safari”"`.

Obviously you'll need to adjust for your particular needs/wants, but you now have the *application process* that **System Events** needs to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript does not work for me but you can use `Accessibility Inspector.app` (bundled with XCode), see [How To Identify Process From A Toolbar Icon or Window?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232416/how-to-identify-process-from-a-toolbar-icon-or-window/232427#232427)